# Comparing NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to compare two dictionaries along with its key and value. My following code returns an error.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"doc_GETNEWS"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"doc_GETNEWS_next"]);

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"doc_GETNEWS_next"]!=nil)
    {

        NSDictionary *firstCache=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"doc_GETNEWS"];
        NSDictionary *secondCache=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"doc_GETNEWS_next"];

        NSLog(@"%@",firstCache);
        NSLog(@"%@",secondCache);
        //not equal then store it to main cache
        if(![firstCache isEqualToDictionary:secondCache])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:secondCache forKey:@"doc_GETNEWS"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
```

I am getting error in

```
if(![firstCache isEqualToDictionary:secondCache])
```

in this statement.like

```
[__NSCFArray isEqualToDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85247a0

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToDictionary:]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x85247a0'
```

NOT that: I got data successfully in Both NSLOG.

Answer (score 4):

That error means your `firstCache` object isn't actually an `NSDictionary` but is actually an `NSArray`.